# How to enable buttons when scroll bar hits bottom with Win32?

Tags: winapi, scrollbar

I'm writing a license agreement dialog box with Win32 and I'm stumped.  As usual with these things I want the "accept/don't accept" buttons to become enabled when the slider of the scroll bar of the richedit control hits bottom, but I can't find a way to get notified of that event.  The earliest I've been able to learn about it is when the user releases the left mouse button.

Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I tried so far:

- `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` in richedit's wndproc
- `EN_MSGFILTER` notification in dlgproc (yes the filter mask is getting set)
- `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` in dlgproc.
- `EN_VSCROLL` notification in dlgproc

I got so desperate I tried polling but that didn't work either because apparently timer messages stop arriving while the mouse button is down on the slider. I tried both:

- timer callback (to poll) in dlgproc
- timer callback (to poll) in richedit's wndproc

Comment: May be beside the pont, but I don't think this is good UI design. It feels like an arbitrary inconvenience. People don't read those things. Making them scroll down before they continue isn't going to change that. A feature like this smacks of marketing/beauracracy informing the design.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sub-class the edit box and intercept the messages to the edit box itself. [Here's an artical on MSDN about subclassing controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx).

EDIT: Some code to demonstrate the scroll bar enabling a button:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

LRESULT __stdcall RichEditSubclass
(
  HWND window,
  UINT message,
  WPARAM w_param,
  LPARAM l_param
)
{
  HWND
    parent = reinterpret_cast <HWND> (GetWindowLong (window, GWL_HWNDPARENT));

  WNDPROC
    proc = reinterpret_cast <WNDPROC> (GetWindowLong (parent, GWL_USERDATA));

  switch (message)
  {
  case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
      SCROLLINFO
        scroll_info = 
        {
          sizeof scroll_info,
          SIF_ALL
        };

      GetScrollInfo (window, SB_VERT, &scroll_info);

      if (scroll_info.nPos + static_cast <int> (scroll_info.nPage) >= scroll_info.nMax ||
          scroll_info.nTrackPos + static_cast <int> (scroll_info.nPage) >= scroll_info.nMax)
      {
        HWND
          button = reinterpret_cast <HWND> (GetWindowLong (parent, 0));

        EnableWindow (button, TRUE);
      }
    }
    break;
  }

  return CallWindowProc (proc, window, message, w_param, l_param);
}

LRESULT __stdcall ApplicationWindowProc
(
  HWND window,
  UINT message,
  WPARAM w_param,
  LPARAM l_param
)
{
  bool
    use_default_proc = false;

  LRESULT
    result = 0;

  switch (message)
  {
  case WM_CREATE:
    {
      CREATESTRUCT
        *creation_data = reinterpret_cast <CREATESTRUCT *> (l_param);

      RECT
        client;

      GetClientRect (window, &client);

      HWND
        child = CreateWindow (RICHEDIT_CLASS,
                              TEXT ("The\nQuick\nBrown\nFox\nJumped\nOver\nThe\nLazy\nDog\nThe\nQuick\nBrown\nFox\nJumped\nOver\nThe\nLazy\nDog"),
                              WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_DISABLENOSCROLL,
                              0, 0, client.right, client.bottom - 30,
                              window,
                              0,
                              creation_data->hInstance,
                              0);

      SetWindowLong (window, GWL_USERDATA, GetWindowLong (child, GWL_WNDPROC));
      SetWindowLong (child, GWL_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast <LONG> (RichEditSubclass));
      SetWindowLong (child, GWL_ID, 0);

      child = CreateWindow (TEXT ("BUTTON"), TEXT ("Go Ahead!"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED, 0, client.bottom - 30, client.right, 30, window, 0, creation_data->hInstance, 0);

      SetWindowLong (window, 0, reinterpret_cast <LONG> (child));
      SetWindowLong (child, GWL_ID, 1);
    }
    break;

  case WM_COMMAND:
    if (HIWORD (w_param) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD (w_param) == 1)
    {
      DestroyWindow (window);
    }
    break;

  default:
    use_default_proc = true;
    break;
  }

  return use_default_proc ? DefWindowProc (window, message, w_param, l_param) : result;
}

int __stdcall WinMain
(
  HINSTANCE instance,
  HINSTANCE unused,
  LPSTR command_line,
  int show
)
{
  LoadLibrary (TEXT ("riched20.dll"));

  WNDCLASS
    window_class = 
    {
      0,
      ApplicationWindowProc,
      0,
      4,
      instance,
      0,
      LoadCursor (0, IDC_ARROW),
      reinterpret_cast <HBRUSH> (COLOR_BACKGROUND + 1),
      0,
      TEXT ("ApplicationWindowClass")
    };

  RegisterClass (&window_class);

  HWND
    window = CreateWindow (TEXT ("ApplicationWindowClass"),
                           TEXT ("Application"),
                           WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           400, 300, 0, 0,
                           instance,
                           0);

  MSG
    message;

  int
    success;

  while (success = GetMessage (&message, window, 0, 0))
  { 
    if (success == -1)
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      TranslateMessage (&message);
      DispatchMessage (&message);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The above doesn't handle the user moving the cursor in the edit box.

Comment: Skizz, I did subclass the richedit control and I did intercept messages that Windows sends to that control. I gave examples of that in my original post. For example, when I said that I had looked for WM_VSCROLL in the richedit's wndproc, it meant that I had substituted my own wndproc for the richedit's default wndproc and was intercepting its WM_VSCROLL message. Treb, I *am* trying to do this the conventional way. I'll l look at some more license agreement screens but I think most of them only enable "Accept" when you scroll to the bottom. (I may have been wrong about both buttons starting off

Comment: Skizz, in reply to your code example, my original post said that I had already tried that. The first example I gave of things I had tried was this: "WM_VSCROLL and WM_LBUTTONUP in richedit's wndproc" That's what you're doing in your example -- responding to WM_VSCROLL in the control's wndproc. Once again -- I'm repeating myself -- I tried that already and it doesn't work for this purpose, because the operating system does not send WM_VSCROLL to the control's wndproc while the user is holding the mouse button down with the mouse cursor on the thumb. That's the problem. What's the point of telli

Comment: The code I posted above works as required using VS2k5. The only real gotcha was that scroll bar position != scroll bar max when the thumb is at the bottom of the scroll bar. The correct test is scroll bar position + page size >= scroll bar max.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem.

Comment: It really does work! The code also tracks the ScrollInfo.nTrackPos which is updated even if the user has not let go of the mouse button!

Comment: The problem is that as long as the user's finger is holding down the mouse button and the mouse cursor is on the slider, Windows doesn't send WM_VSCROLL to the controls's wndproc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the EM_GETTHUMB message. (Assuming Rich Edit 2.0 or later).

If you are lucky this bottom position will match EM_GETLINECOUNT.

Comment: EM_GETTHUMB doesn't count in lines.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is possible, I don't think you should do it that way - the user will have no clue why the buttons are disabled. This can be very confusing, and confusing the user should be avoided at all costs ;-)

That's why most license dialogs have radio buttons for accept/decline with decline enabled by default, so you actively have to enable accept.

Comment: Every license agreement  i seen up to know have this feature.

Comment: I doubt that. Anyway, my answer stays: Don't do it.

Comment: I wouldn't say every license agreement has it, in fact most I've seen don't. But I have seen some that do, so it certainly is possible.

Comment: Yup, I've seen the answer above. It can be done, will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend starting up **Spy++** and seeing which windows messages are getting sent to where.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(VS.60).aspx