# How to "notify" parent window about "scroll event" of child window "list box" control in WIN32 API?

Tags: winapi, listbox, scroll, notify

How to **"notify"** the parent window about the **"scroll event"** of its child window, a **"list box"** control, each time it is scrolled up or down in **WIN32 API**?

I am trying to make a *dictionary* using the *WIN32 API*. I created a *parent window*, and then created a child window *list box* control in it.

I want to add **"50 word lists"** at a time to the list box control from the database, so that the application does not take time at all during the start up.

And then, I want to keep a track of the **"scroll bar position"** (the **"SCROLLINFO"** structure's **"nPos"** value) of the list box control as the user scrolls up or down the word lists, so that I can call a function that adds 50 more words at the end of the list box when it has been almost scrolled up to the bottom.

In the **main window procedure** function, inside the **"switch"** statement I used the **"WM_VSCROLL"** window message hoping to catch the child window list box control’s scroll event. The child window list box control has **"LBS_NOTIFY"** style. But all in vain! The list box control’s scroll event is not being notified to its parent window. The parent window also is not doing anything in the **"WM_VSCROLL"** message for its child window list box control’s scroll event.

Please kindly help me, guide me, show me with code examples how to **"notify"** the parent window about the **"scroll event"** of its child window, a **"list box"** control, each time it is scrolled up or down in WIN32 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrolling messages are only sent to the window that is actually being scrolled, in this case the ListBox.  `LBS_NOTIFY` only applies to a few select messages, which do not include scrolling messages. You would have to subclass the ListBox via either `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()` and have your subclass procedure catch the scrolling messages and forward the info to the parent window as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I also found a very useful link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239866/how-to-enable-buttons-when-scroll-bar-hits-bottom-with-win32?rq=1